# No replay button when YouTube video ends

Tags: youtube

I'm not sure if its due to some Chrome extensions that I installed but I'm not getting any replay button when the video ends. It just shows a few suggested videos after it ends.

Is everyone else getting the same thing?

How can I replay a video (doesn't matter if it's automatic) without refreshing the page?

Comment: Is this on the YouTube site itself, or an embedded video? On the YouTube website I get a replay button in the bottom left once the video ends. (In Google Chrome)

Comment: Hm...true. Just checked office's chrome. It has the controls there after the video ends. Guess its some extension I have back home.

Comment: What do you see instead of the the replay button? Do you get the bottom control bar at all?

Comment: @w3d Yeah. I don't see the control bar at all after the video ends.